# How to create a new item in the database upon opening Django CreateView

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to auto-create an object in database in the background, upon opening a link in Django using Django generic class views, here is my code :

```py
class BuyInvoiceItemCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.BuyInvoiceItems
    fields = "__all__"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        models.BuyInvoice.objects.create(number=0)
        return render(request, "Point_of_sale/buyinvoiceitems_form.html")
```

I've tried to override the get method, but it creates 2 objects every time I open the link instead of 1 object.